# MySQL stalls after OPTIMIZE TABLE

Tags: python, mysql

When I run an `OPTIMIZE TABLE foo` MySQL seems to stall on that query.

```
> show full processlist;
| 798 | root | localhost       | turbo | Query   |    1 | Waiting for table metadata lock | optimize table foo |
```

There are no other running queries. Server Version is 5.5.54

**Reproducing**:

*Create tables like:*

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `bar` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
CREATE TABLE `bar` (
  `faz` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

*Create a python script like:*

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import  MySQLdb, time

dbc = MySQLdb.connect(db="turbo", host="localhost", user="", passwd="")
crsr = dbc.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
crsr.execute("select count(*) from foo left join bar on bar.faz=foo.bar")
print crsr.fetchall()

# keep connection open
while(1):
  time.sleep(1)
```

*Perform a query in MySQL-shell like:*

```
mysql> optimize table foo;
```

*Another shell*

```
mysql> show processlist;
+-----+------+-----------+-------+---------+------+---------------------------------+--------------------+
| Id  | User | Host      | db    | Command | Time | State                           | Info               |
+-----+------+-----------+-------+---------+------+---------------------------------+--------------------+
| 236 | root | localhost | turbo | Query   |  230 | Waiting for table metadata lock | optimize table foo |
| 308 | root | localhost | turbo | Sleep   |  232 |                                 | NULL               |
| 309 | root | localhost | NULL  | Query   |    0 | NULL                            | show processlist   |
+-----+------+-----------+-------+---------+------+---------------------------------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This query will never finish. There was no problem on older versions of MySQL, Python, Debian etc - so this may be a bug somewhere or I miss something due to a changed API?

Edit:
*This seems to be a bug when a query with **joined** tables were executed and the connection kept open.
Also this bug does not occur every time - restarting the python script may produce this behavior in most times.*

Regards

Coyer

Comment: Just found out that adding `dbc.commit()` after fetching the data makes it working every time. stupid since there should be no need to commit selects... also it's MyISAM and autocommit is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with 1.2.0, MySQLdb disables autocommit by default.

So by adding `dbc.autocommit(True)`after creating the connection seems to solve this issue - anyway it makes **no sense** commiting select-queries - even on MyISAM tables (which do not support transactions at all)!

I assume this is a bug in MySQLdb as I cannot reproduce a similar behaviour in other languages - also this behaviour is not reproducable every time.